# Call web service in background while accessing UI

Tags: web-services, background, xamarin.ios

I have a situation where as soon as app starts i have to call a web service to post unsaved data back to the server while i keep on accessing the app. I should be able to navigate to different views, perform UI tasks.
I can use Task

```c#
 Task CallWebService()
 {
     return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        // make your service call. 
     });  
 }
 CallWebService().ContinueWith(task => {

     if(task.isFaulted)
         throw new AggregateException(task.Exception.InnerException.Message);

     // Runs when the task is finished
     InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
         // Hide your activity indicator here. 
         StopActivityIndicator();
     });

 });
```

I dont know where to call InvokeOnMainThread as user could be on any view. How do we handle that.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know where to call it? Like in what file, what method, what part of the app?

Comment: I don't know how to handle it. My logic is every 2 min check if there is any thing un saved in database, if there, then call web service in background without disturbing user activity. As user can be on any view while web service is called. So what goes in InvokeOnMainThread() i dont know which main ui thread.

Comment: You call InvokeOnMainThread from your background thread.  Why do you care which view is active?  What is wrong with the code you have?  What do you want to do when the thread completes - just stop the activity indicator?  Or something else?

Comment: It seems you would need to have your activity indicator in some ViewController that is accessible at all times, like the NavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the downloader as a static class with event handlers (or use dependency resolver). In your view controllers override ViewDidAppear and ViewDidDisappear where you will subscribe and unsubscribe to the events.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate.cs, You can add your "Task" to the FinishedLaunching override and the OnActivated override, assuming you have a way to determine if there is any "unsaved" data, that needs to be sent to the server.

```
public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
{

}
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{

}
```